# What does Mumufa mean by "Stinky drivers repel their Blades"?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

In the Argentum Trade Guild on the Goldmouth Flight Deck, there's an Informant named Mumufa. One piece of information he sells is "Stench" which says:

> Stinky Drivers repel their Blades. Too far and specials become impossible.

I understand the second part means specials can't be used when you're far from your blade, but what about the first part? Are stinky drivers actually a thing? Or is this just flavor text?

[image: purchases for Mumufa]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Xenoblade wikia](https://xenoblade.fandom.com/wiki/Stench_(status)):

> Stench is a status effect and a party debuff that **repels Blades** from their Drivers during combat.

And, well, *stench* is a strong smell. So that's your "stinky drivers".